# is it possible to generate random ill-conditioned sparse matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random-matrices

I know how to generate ill-conditioned dense matrices (use 'gallery'). I do not know how to generate ill-conditioned sparse matrices. Anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a sparsity pattern in mind? If not, what do you mean by "sparse"?

Comment: @Ian Maybe I can input the percentage of number of nonzero and the dimension of the matrix, then output an ill-conditioned matrix which is in sparse format for any pattern?

Comment: What is an "ill-conditioned" matrix?